# Camel recipient List doesnt resolve special characters

Tags: apache-camel, apache-servicemix

I have a camel route which processes xml data and send to http endpoint. below is my http endpoint.

```
.recipientList(simple("http://${header.httpUri}?xmlData=${body}"))
```

where the httpUri ill get it from db hence set it header and used. Body contains xml data with special characters of different language. Whenever it tries to resolve endpoint, since the body contains special characters, ResolveEndpointException occurs. The tracer log shows the body with special characters resolved like %20B etc.,

I feel the problem is with `simple()` SimpleBuilder.

Is there any other way to resolve endpoint dynamically???

Comment: Use HTTP POST to post your data, not HTTP GET.

Answer (score 0):

Tried POST, HTTP_URI and HTTP_QUERY. It didnt work. Then found it was related to character encoding. My request contained some ISO-8859-9 encoding data. I send request with character encoding ISO-8859-9, and it worked.